# How to replace an element on click, then reinsert it when the inserted element is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using bootstrap for this project and what I want to achieve is this. When the navbar toggle is clicked the three horizontal icons are removed and they are replaced with a glyphicon.

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
```

I'm using the remove() and prepend() handlers to achieve this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.navbar-toggle').click(function() {
    $('.icon-bar').remove();
    $(".navbar-toggle").prepend('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>');
  });
});
```

It's removing and replacing the icon bars with the cross but I can't work out how I can make the it change back into the horizontal icon bars when the cross is clicked. At the moment it just adds more crosses. Sorry if it's a stupid question, I'm still new at this.

http://jsfiddle.net/Gvauv/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
$('.navbar-toggle').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('glyphicon glyphicon-remove').find('.icon-bar').toggleClass("hidden");
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Gvauv/1/)**

Answer (score 2):

with bootstrap you have the class `hidden`, so you can add your glyphicon in the html and just hide it. something like this:

```
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove hidden"></span>
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.navbar-toggle').click(function() {
    $('.icon-bar').toggleClass('hidden');
    $('.glyphicon').toggleClass('hidden');
  });
});
```

Comment: perfect answer, as icon-bar is needed anyway later

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.navbar-toggle').click(function() {
    $('.icon-bar').toggleClass("hidden");
    $('.navbar-toggle').toggleClass('glyphicon glyphicon-remove');
  });
});
```